# Testing Paperclip file uploading with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, paperclip

I don't really care about testing file uploads, but since I have `validates_attachment_presence`, etc.. in my model, rspec is complaining.

So now I'm creating my model with these attributes in the spec to try and shut it up:

```
@attr = {
  :name => "value for name",
  :title => "value for title",
  :content => "value for content",
  :pic_file_name => "example.jpg",
  :pic_content_type => "image/jpg",
  :pic_file_size => "8192",
  :pic_updated_at => nil
}
```

This doesn't work, though.

I found this: http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/mocking-paperclip-with-rspec
So I tried something like this:

```
Post.should_receive(:save_attached_files).and_return(true)
```

Which doesn't work either. How do I appease RSpec?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unit testing paperclip uploads with Rspec (Rails)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256012/unit-testing-paperclip-uploads-with-rspec-rails)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the model `has_attached_file :pic`, you should be able to just point the `pic` attribute at some file and all should be dandy.

Meaning something like `@attr = { :pic => File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'spec', 'fixtures', 'file.png')) }`

Comment: This used to work for me, but does not seem to work when upgrading to paperclip 3.1.4 from 2.5.0.

Comment: @DavidN.Welton what kind of error (if any) do you get? I don't have much experience with Paperclip 3.

Comment: What fixed it was doing: `mymodel.attachedimage = File.open(....)` rather than `attachedimage = "file/location/foo.jpg"`

Comment: @DavidN.Welton Did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @JasonSwett see the comment above - you have to pass it a file handle rather than the file name.

Comment: Since some people have had issues, I'd like to update the answer, but it's been a while since I've used paperclip. Could someone suggest an edit, perhaps @DavidN.Welton? Thanks!